# Connecting a USB-C HUB to my USB-A-only desktop

Tags: laptop, usb, display, desktop, usb-c

I am looking at purchasing a hub like [this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Multiport-Adapter-Splitter-Charging-Chromebook/dp/B08BF8XMZP/ref=sr_1_8?dchild=1&keywords=hdmi%20hub&qid=1603554296&sr=8-8) so I can easily connect my two monitors, mouse, and keyboard to my laptop, and also easily switch between laptop and desktop with minimal effort.

The issue comes with my desktop, where my motherboard (i5-4690K) only has USB-A (3.0) ports. I have tried to search for a simple USB-C to USB-A adapter, but none of them seem to support video, only charging/data transfer.

Has anyone got any other solutions? I am happy to spend what I need to.

Thanks!

Comment: There isn’t a solution to your problem.  Your computer doesn’t support video over USB.

Comment: i5-4690K is not a motherboard or a laptop model.. it's a processor.  There might be other solutions/workarounds to your problem but how can we guess with only a processor?  @Ramhound isn't wrong.. but he also isn't being as helpful as possible.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - It does not take any knowledge of what motherboard the author has to determine the motherboard doesn’t support video over USB if they don’t have the USB Type-C (specifically USB 3.2 Gen 2).

Comment: @Ramhound,  I knew I couldn't answer his question but it is possible to point out the options he has avail. to him.  No offense intended.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution. If you can afford one of modern high-performance video cards like [Radeon Pro W5700](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-amd-radeon-pro-w5700-workstation-graphics-card/apd/490-bfsr/graphic-video-cards), it will come with embedded USB 3.2 xHCI controller with Type-C port on the face plate. Then you can connect your fancy Type-C docking station and enjoy all features provided by USB 3.2 interface.

[image]

Comment: There are less expensive options.  A USB-C card with DP passthrough will work if the desktop already has a DP output port.  One example I found:  http://www.sunix.com/en/product_detail.php?pid=1909

Comment: @MacGuffin, thanks, this is a good find. Why don't you embed a picture to your answer, of how it gets connected, for clarity? https://www.sunix.com/upload/product/2020/20200207110449_feat-UPD-v2-en-3.jpg

Answer (score 0):

To plug a USB-C device into a computer requires a USB-C port on the computer.  An adapter to USB-A defeats the capability of the hub to carry any video information since USB-A has 9 pins and USB-C has 24 pins, at least 4 of those pins are needed for video.  The reason adapters for plugging USB-C docks into USB-A ports are hard to find is because such adapters violate the USB specification, to the point that they are fire hazards.

There is a company that offers a way to get video over a USB-A port, called DisplayLink.  DisplayLink is also the chips they sell to dock manufacturers that work like you describe.  This is something of a "hack" because USB-A was never designed to carry video but I hear good things about it.

Don't look for an adapter to plug a USB-C device into a USB-A port.  If you find one they will not work for you.  Look for a DisplayLink dock.  They will cost more than the USB-C products because they are more complicated.  It's up to you if they are worth it.